# В C# не работает Text Edit

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую, начал изучать C# с нуля по книге "*Изучаем C#*" Эндрю Стиллмена. В книге все происходит в VS2012 for Windows 8. Соответственно на компьютер именно эту версия и поставил, чтобы мог выполнять все действия буквально.
На одном этапе необходимо изменить текст через Edit Text контекстного меню. И я получаю вот это сообщение с ***ошибкой***:

> Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteException
>   Unable  to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Text.TextDecorations' to
>   type 'System.Windows.TextDecorationCollection'.    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextBlockEditProxy.Instantiate()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextEditProxy.AddToScene(Boolean
>   visible)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.AddEditProxyToScene(TextEditProxy
>   textEditProxy, Boolean visible)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.FindOrCreateEditProxy(SceneNode
>   textElement, Boolean active)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.BeginTextEdit(SceneNode
>   textElement)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.EditDifferentElement(SceneNode
>   element, Boolean returnFocus)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.Text.TextToolBehavior.OnAttach()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Tools.EventRouter.PushBehavior(ToolBehavior
>   newActiveBehavior)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.View.SceneView.TryEnterTextEditMode(Boolean
>   textElementOnly)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.SceneCommands.EditTextCommand.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Utility.Commands.CommandTarget.ExecuteCommand(String
>   commandName, CommandInvocationSource invocationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.Utility.UserInterface.CommandBarButtonBase.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
>   Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)    at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)    at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.RunApplication()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationProcess.DesignProcessViewProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__6()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: А переустановить не пробовали?

Comment: И поправте заголовок - VS2012 вместо С#, и метки тоже - С# это не с++.

Comment: Изменить текст чего?

Comment: Код, который меняет текст покажите нам

Comment: @0xdb Да, даже полностью с виндой. Поправил, спасибо за замечание.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko изменить текст кнопки, или TextBlock

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk честно говоря не совсем понял, как это сделать. Я просто еще сооовсем новичок.

Comment: @AlexAnder Если вы делаете изменение текста с помощью кода на C# - скопируйте программный код, который вы используете. Если визуально - попробуйте сделать скриншот.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk Хорошо, попробую. Правда не знаю, то ли от меня требуется)

https://ibb.co/bK1qMQ

И когда я нажимаю в меню Edit Text (на любом объекте), то выскакивает та ошибка, что выше.

Comment: @AlexAnder Проект сможете прислать? ivankramarchuk1217@gmail.com или выложите куда нибудь. Я открою у себя и мы сможем понять - это ошибка у вас с системой или что-то не так с кодом xaml.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/NBnG/nb6PvvrQy

Вот, пожалуйста. А как считаете, может это быть из-за того, что у меня Win10 стоит?

Comment: @AlexAnder выделите элемент. Далее в правом нижнем углу есть окно properties. Там Вы найдете свойство text. Попробуйте его поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите. Во первых вы можете менять текст непосредственно в XAML. Это нижняя часть экрана:

[image: Visual Studio]

Во вторых похоже что крэш - баг именно Visual Studio 2012 Express, т.к. на Visual Studio 2015 редактирование текста работает без проблем (я скачал ваш проект и проверил).

Советую установить Visual Studio 2017 community edition или Visual Studio 2015 community edition и делать все на нем. Если будут какие то отличия интерфейса от описанного в книге - тогда на небольшое время откроете проект в Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Comment: Странно. Просто автор книги использует VS2012 Express for Win8, а я повторяю за ним точь-в-точь. Видимо проблема именно из-за моей Windows10. 
Но, к сожалению, и с Visual Studio 2017 Communityу меня проблема. Ни в какую не хочет она открывать проект. Пишет про несовместимость. А начать с нуля тоже не получается, так как в VS2017 отсутствуют те шаблоны, которые есть в VS2012. Подскажете?

Comment: Мне Visual Studio 2015 предложила преобразовать проект для поддержки Windows 8.1 вместо Windows 8, после этого проект открылся и заработал. Ваш проект после преобразования: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ed0kt0jfg1vneq/Save%20the%20Humans.zip?dl=0

Comment: Фух, после некоторых мучений я кое-как разобрался. Мне необходимо было в VS2015 установить пакет SDK для win8.1 и все заработало как надо. К сожалению, в VS2017 не получилось добиться правильного результата. Всем огромное спасибо)